# Find button in html using Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

i want to find and hide button "Add" in typescript.
How to do it ?

```
<div class="edittoolbar">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" title="Add">
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" title="Modify">
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" title="Delete">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

i using this code to find button but it not success.
because myNodeList1.length is return =0 , so i can not continue to find it.
please help me. Thank you!

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div.edittoolbar div.btn-group') ;
console.log(nodes);

const myNodeList1: NodeListOf<Element> = nodes.item(0).childNodes ;  // node
console.log(myNodeList1.length) ;
```

[image]

i expecting have a ways to do it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm sorry, I cannot reproduce your results. Please share a working example, e.g. using https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vanilla-typescript-vanilla-ts

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector()` returns the first Element

```js
const nodes = document.querySelector(".btn.btn-primary")
```

`childNodes` returns all child nodes, including text nodes (including spaces and line breaks) and comment nodes. this can lead to unexpected results, so be careful.

if you need purely element nodes, the `children` property is more appropriate.

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll("div.edittoolbar div.btn-group");
const myNodeList1 = nodes.item(0).children; // childNodes => children
```

Comment: Dear, Do you know why myNodeList1 length it =0 ?  i see it seem have 3 element , Thanks

Comment: @ngoctuannguyen created an additional answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

to access array elements by index you have to use []<'square brackets'> , here you are using ()<'parenthesis'>;

right way

```
const myNodeList1: NodeListOf<Element> = nodes.item[0].childNodes ;  // node
console.log(myNodeList1.length) ;
```

change

```
item(0) --> item[0]
```

Comment: Dear ,const myNodeList1: NodeListOf<Element> = nodes.item[0].childNodes ;  not working. thanks

Comment: `item()`is function get node, so correct syntax!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your results.
Your code gives the following compile error:

> Type 'NodeListOf<ChildNode>' is not assignable to type
> 'NodeListOf<Element>'.

I have tried this:

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll("div.btn-group")
const myNodeList1: NodeListOf<ChildNode> = nodes[0].childNodes
console.log(myNodeList1)
console.log(myNodeList1.length)
```

and the result is 7. Button 'Add' is `myNodeList1[1]`.

A simple way to find the button with title="Add" is:

```
const node: HTMLButtonElement | null = document.querySelector('button[title="Add"]')
```

If you still have a problem, please share a complete, but small working application.